# FileVersionInfo call from within IIS Application

Tags: c#, iis

I'm having a problem detecting the FileVersion of a file.
My code runs from an IIS virtual application (upon an incoming HTTP request).

When run I run the following, the FileVersion is null:

```
FileVersionInfo version = FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo(file.FullName);    
version.FileVersion ==> null
```

I've doubled checked, the `file.FullName` is correct `(File.Exists(FullName)` returns `true`).

When I run the same code from a non IIS virtual application (simple .EXE) on the same file it works fine.
Also, when I run the IIS virtual application on a different file, it also works fine.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible reason could be if the assembly you are inspecting has several version information resources attached to them. Depending on the culture of the program calling the `GetVersionInfo` method it is possible that a non-existing version information is returned.

Comment: By *the culture* I mean the current thread culture of your application.

Comment: There is a single resource and the culture is the same between the current running thread and the assembly.

Comment: But did you check if the current culture in the ASP.NET application is the same compared to the culture used in the console application (where you stated that it works)?